# ConnectionString with DataDirectory (c#, sqlserver)

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, wpf

I created an application in c# with wpf using EntityFramework.
When I create the setup it works fine on my computer but when I install it on another computer I get this error

> A file activation error occured. The physical file name `\Data\myDb.mdf` may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additionnal errors, and retry the operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

**Here is my `App.config`**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>

        <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;
             AttachDbFileName='|DataDirectory|\Data\myDb.mdf';
             Initial Catalog=myDb.mdf; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

      </connectionStrings>
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
      </startup>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191659/discussion-on-question-by-2kferd-connectionstring-with-datadirectory-c-sqlser).

Comment: @2kFerd: Where is the `myDb.mdf` file located on the computer where it fails?

Comment: @mm8 this is the full path after installing `C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\AppFolder\Data\myDb.mdf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set the value for `|DataDirectory|` during runtime:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\AppFolder\")
```

Or replace `|DataDirectory|` with an absolute path in your configuration file.

Comment: When I replace `|DataDirectory|` with the absolute path, I get this error **Cannot create file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Company\AppFolder\Data\myDb.mdf ` because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation** . But when I change I get a **NullPointerException**

Comment: "Change"? What if you remove the file? Where do you get this exception in your code?

Comment: I get it when I try to access to the database

Comment: It works fine after deleting all caches and the old MSSQLLocalDB in SQL Server LocalDB folder.